# How can I use my LinkedIn profile to find employment in another location?

Tags: linkedin, networking, relocation

I've been getting really a lot of LinkedIn profile views, invites from recruiters, etc. However, all of them come from my current location in Europe. Thing is I'd like to move overseas, to US west coast.

How can I indicate that in my LinkedIn profile? How can I make my LinkedIn profile more visible to recruiters in particular area, that's not my current location?

Comment: I don't think this is a very good site to ask about LinkedIn-specific questions.  this is a question about the capabilities of the LinkedIn platform, and would be better asked of the support on LinkedIn itself, rather than a tangentially-related QA site elsewhere.

Comment: I know this question is closed, but when I did a relocation accross the US, I applied for specific jobs, and put on my resume that I was relocating to the city I was targeting.  Don't expect to get a relocation package using this method.  Also if you don't already have a VISA that will limit you as well.  But using your linkedin profile to find a job is a very passive method.  You need to be active and put out the resumes and applications yourself for the jobs you want.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried indicating in your profile that you are interested only in positions on the US West Coast?

Being direct, and indicating specifically what you are seeking is usually the best way to get what you want.

Comment: I'm quite certain, that LI searches via some kind of geo-proximity, not sure how such indication in text of profile would help him.